# How do I get GDB to break out of a loop?

Tags: c, gdb, goto, break

I can tell GDB to return from a function immediately with `return`, and call a function with `call myFunction`.

But how do I get it break out of the current loop?  i.e. to act as if it's hit a `break;` statement.

Is `jump myfile.c:<linenumber>` the way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to execute the loop normally and `break` out of it, or alter execution by skipping the loop entirely? Asking to differentiate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651073/is-there-a-gdb-command-to-finish-a-loop-construct

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`jump` looks like what you want.  See [Continuing at a Different Address](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Jumping.html#Jumping)

Comment: `jump [line number]` got me out of the loop and to the line I wanted to go. This is the answer I was looking for (and it's also the one that OP accepted). I have no idea why the other (poorly written, in my opinion, at least until I edited it) answer got more upvotes.

Answer (score 26):

You can use `until` to make the loop end.

You should give it at the end of the loop.

This is useful if you do not need to step in to iterate a loop.

Comment: If I read the docs right ( http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_38.html ) that's equivalent to setting a temporary breakpoint after the loop - I was looking to break out of the loop.

Comment: this tip is still valuable, tho not an answer to the question. Maybe the question should be expanded to include a spcific statement that you do not want this feature?

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why this has more upvotes than the older and accepted answer?

Comment: @Nike the 'jump' is a rather crude way of forcing the cursor to move, and involves figuring out the right line number. `until` is purpose built for skipping over for loops

Comment: @Cheetaiean "until" what? "Until" is usually a word that comes before another word.

Answer (score 5):

I do this:
1. do a source listing.
2. Set a breakpoint at the next line where loop ends.
3. Continue

Comment: You don't even need a real breakpoint.  You can use `until` to tell it to continue until a certain line number.  This is a one-time breakpoint.

Comment: That's not breaking out of the loop, that's waiting until the loop ends (which might be never).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651073/is-there-a-gdb-command-to-finish-a-loop-construct/

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways could be to set the condition of the loop to false. But this would mean that you would have to wait for the current iteration to finish.

So to summarize the steps would be:
1. Set a breakpoint at the last line of the loop
2. Continue
3. When breakpoint hits, set the loop condition variable to false.

It won't work as direct break statement though.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I usually do, but I'm sure there must be a way of imitating `break;`