# Is there a gdb command to finish a loop construct?

Tags: debugging, loops, gdb, walkthrough

In gdb, I have the `finish` command to easily finish execution of a function frame, often when walking through code in the debugger, after looking at a few iterations of a loop, I'd like to finish the loop and continue walking after it.  Presently, I do this by setting a break point on the first line after the loop and `continue`, however, it would be really handy if there was a simple gdb command to have the same effect of this but not require a break point to be set and later cleared.

Is there anyway in gdb to finish execution of the current loop being executed?

Comment: `jump` execution altering version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200556/how-do-i-get-gdb-to-break-out-of-a-loop

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> Is there a gdb command to finish a loop construct?

Execute `until` on the last line of the loop, or `until NNN` where `NNN` is the last line of the loop.

```
(gdb) help until
Execute until the program reaches a source line greater than the current
or a specified location (same args as break command) within the current frame.
```

> not require a break point to be set and later cleared.

Temporary breakpoints automatically clear themselves:

```
(gdb) help tbreak
Set a temporary breakpoint.
Like "break" except the breakpoint is only temporary,
so it will be deleted when hit.  Equivalent to "break" followed
by using "enable delete" on the breakpoint number.
```

Comment: So what's the difference between `until` and `advance`?

Comment: @Jester "This command is similar to until, but advance will not skip over recursive function calls, and the target location doesn't have to be in the same frame as the current one." https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html

Comment: Also it looks like `advance` is much more precise in that it only jumps to the actual code location.

Answer (score 6):

`gdb` doesn't know where a loop ends so it can't do that. I think the best you can do is use the `advance` command with a location after the loop.